# How can I convert an object to a nullable generic in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class which contains answers for questions

The answers are stored in a string

I have created a method like so:

```
public void set_answer(object obj){
   .....
}
```

which will take as an arguement a variable, and according to the question type will change it into a string representation, so for example if the answer is a string it will keep it as it is, if it is a DateTime it will change it to a yyyy-MM-dd format plus about 8 other transformations

I wish to create the opposite method, which will return the answer in the original type

I have the following code:

```
public T? get_answer<T>() {
    //this means that the answer has not been set yet
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_answer)) return null; 
    object reply = null;
    switch (_answer_type) {
        ...do stuff here to transform the string to the correct type, which will match T
    }
    <here is the problem>
}
```

At the end of this code, the reply variable will contain either null or a variable of type T

how can I return that value?

in my code I will be using it like this :

```
 DateTime? date = question.get_answer<DateTime>();
```

which should return null if no answer has been set yet or the request was for an incorrect type (i.e. asked for a datetime answer on a Tupple question)

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: Apply .NET naming [conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx), f.e. `set_answer`->`SetAnswer`, `get_answer`->`GetAnswer`

Comment: Are you just wanting to return `new Nullable<T>(value)`?

Comment: Tim I tried it, doesn't seem to solve my problem , DavidG basically I want the caller to send a request saying "give me the answer in THAT form" and if the question has an answer, and that answer is convertible to THAT form, then it should return the answer in THAT form (integer, date ,tuple<date,date>,list<int> and others) otherwise it should return null

Comment: by the way I know I could make get_answer return object and then cast it at the caller's end, but I was wondering if I could avoid it using generics

Comment: Note that `Nullable` has a constraint on it's generic type that requires the type to be a `struct` (aka value type).  So you cannot have a nullable string for example.

Comment: yes that is the error I've been getting, I guess all I can do is turn it to object get_answer<T>() and then cast it at the caller's end if it is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `MyMethod<T>` and for the most part it consists of code like `if (T is Type1) {...} else if (T is Type2) {...} else if [etc]`, then very often you **shouldn't be using a generic method in the first place**.

In such a case I would recommend to use this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public string _answer;

  public DateTime? GetDate()
  {
      DateTime result;
      if (DateTime.TryParse(_answer, out result)) return result;
      return null;
  }

  public int? GetInt()
  {
      int result;
      if (int.TryParse(_answer, out result)) return result;
      return null;
  }
  // etc
}
```

and to test it:

```
public void TestIt()
{
    var x = new MyClass { _answer = "gaga" };
    var d = x.GetDate();
    var i = x.GetInt();
    // etc
}
```

Or if you must use a single obj...

```
public void TestIt()
{
    var x = new MyClass { _answer = "gaga" };
    object obj = x.GetDate();
    if (obj == null) obj = x.GetInt();
    // etc
}
```

Or in one statement:

```
public void TestIt()
{
    var x = new MyClass { _answer = "gaga" };
    var obj = (object) x.GetDate() ?? x.GetInt() /* ?? [etc] */ ;
}
```

Comment: well my method is more like 
if (T is Type1 && _question_type is QuestionTypes.<something>)
But I get what you're saying, I guess I'll change it, looks cleaner thanks